# Как выделить память из стека явно? С++

Tags: c++, память

Разбираюсь с тем, как работают аллокаторы. С обычными аллокаторами все понятно, грубо говоря это обертка над оператором new. Но как работают аллокаторы, выделяющие память из стека? Если нужно выделить определенное количество памяти из стека под определенное количество элементов фиксированного размера, то как это делает аллокатор?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это делает компилятор во время компиляции, но если хочется, чтобы было АПАСНА и АДРЕНАЛИН, `alloca()` к вашим услугам:

> ```
>    #include <alloca.h>
>
>    void *alloca(size_t size);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>    The alloca() function allocates size bytes of space in the stack
>    frame of the caller.  This temporary space is automatically freed
>    when the function that called alloca() returns to its caller.
> ```

*Функция выделяет `size` штук байт из стека того кто ее вызвал. Память будет освобождена автоматически, когда произойдет возврат из функции, вызвавшей `alloca()`*

Опасность состоит в том, что если просчитаться с размером, получится название данного сайта со всеми вытекающими из этого последствиями.

Comment: Это не совсем то, что я хотел услышать. За alloca спасибо, но нет ли другого способа выделить явно память на стеке?

Comment: Единственный корректный (с точки зрения Стандарта) способ это сделать - объявить переменную или массив фиксированной длины. Все прочие способы являются переусложненной реализацией вышеописанного.

Comment: Но если я хочу написать свой аллокатор, например, можно ли это сделать как-то без alloca()?

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, что вы хотите услышать. Из вашего вопроса следует, что вы испытываете желание (странное), выделять память динамически и брать ее со стека. Я вам ответил, как это сделать. Теперь вы хотите какой-то *другой ответ*. Какой?

Comment: Я вроде понятно сформировал вопрос: Я хочу написать свой аллокатор, который будет брать память со стека. Разве можно ли это сделать без alloca(), посредством Единственного корректного метода - объявление переменной или массива

Comment: Да, можно - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049657/stack-buffer-based-stl-allocator

Только размер будет не динамическим

Comment: Думаю это то что надо, буду разбираться, спасибо

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что в качестве буфера в таком случае будет использоваться массив фиксированной длины и нужного типа?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128031/discussion-between-gbg-and-comeinrage).

Comment: А почему опасно?

Comment: @Mikhailo Опасность состоит в том, что если просчитаться с размером, получится название данного сайта со всеми вытекающими из этого последствиями.

Comment: @gbg Это всегда опасно. Независимо от использования `alloca`.